# Enable close button in UIWebView

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I need to display webview in cocos2D game. I used this code. But it is not displaying close button, how can I enable close button? Here is screen that I want:

[image]

Code Used:

```
CGRect webFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

UIWebView* myWebView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame] autorelease];
myWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
myWebView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
myWebView.delegate = self;
[self.navController.view addSubview:myWebView];

[myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://biggooseegg.com/moregamesscreen"]]];
```

Some other doubts: How can I get rounded border for this web view?

[Here is my sample](http://www.4shared.com/zip/ixFhVeQZ/webViewSampleCocos2d.html) that not completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The close button isn't part of UIWebView, you'll have to add it yourself.

Rounded corners can be achieved by displaying said rounded corners background image behind the UIWebView. You can use a CCSprite for that. Then make the web view fit inside the background image.